# How to set session in browser from java desktop application?

Tags: java, javascript, swing, session, awt

I am trying to open a browser using java desktop application,& want to set the session in browser.
 I find out a methods to set the cookie in browser using some methods,but can not find out to set the session.

One possible solution i can think is:- call a javascript function from java,Pass the session variable value to javascript function & set the session using js function.

Edit:- I will be validating the user in java desktop application & will be opening a tab in browser after successful authentication.

Any other alternative in java directly ??

Thanks.

Comment: Is seems like you'd need to pass the session ID as part of the URL you are opening that the page can respond to. Something like: myurl.com?sessionID=xyz

Comment: @crig i don't want it to be visible to user,its a kind of machine authentication.One more problem with parameter is,for each & every request i need to send it in parameter,which is a highly tough job for me.